# What do the zeros in python function bytecode mean?

Tags: python, bytecode

I'm trying to teach myself about how python bytecode works so I can do some stuff with manipulating functions' code (just for fun, not for real usage) so I started with some simple examples, such as:

```
def f(x):
    return x + 3/x
```

The bytecode is*:

```
(124, 0, 0, 100, 1, 0, 124, 0, 0, 20, 23, 83)
```

So it makes sense to me that `124` is the `LOAD_FAST` bytecode, and the name of the object being loaded is `f.__code__.co_varnames[0]` where `0` is the number after `124`. And `100` indicates a `LOAD_CONST` to load `f.__code__.co_consts[1]` where `1` is the number after `100`. But then there are a bunch of auxiliary zeros, like the second and third and fifth zeros that seem to serve no purpose, at least to me. What do they indicate?

Textual bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              9 BINARY_DIVIDE       
             10 BINARY_ADD          
             11 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

*Note: In Python 3 (where bytecodes may be different from above), the bytecode can be found via:

```
>>> list(f.__code__.co_code)
[124, 0, 100, 1, 124, 0, 27, 0, 23, 0, 83, 0]
```

Comment: I ran `dis.dis()` on your function and added the textual version of the bytecode. Feel free to rollback if you'd rather leave it as it was.

Comment: That's a nice addition, thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A large number of bytecodes take arguments (any bytecode with a codepoint at or over [`dis.HAVE_ARGUMENT`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-HAVE_ARGUMENT). Those that do have a 2-byte argument, in little-endian order.

You can see the definition for what bytecodes Python currently uses and what they mean in the [`dis` module documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-HAVE_ARGUMENT).

With 2 bytes you can give any bytecode an argument value between 0 and 65535, for bytecodes than need more, you can *prefix* the bytecode with the [`EXTENDED_ARG` bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-EXTENDED_ARG), adding 2 more bytes for a value between 0 and 4294967295. In theory you could use `EXTENDED_ARG` multiple times, but the CPython interpreter uses `int` for the `oparg` variable and is thus for practical purposes limited to 4-byte values.

As of Python 3.4 the `dis` module provides you with [`Instruction` instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.Instruction) that make it easier to introspect each bytecode and their arguments. Using this we can walk through the byte codes you found for your function `f`:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x + 3/x
... 
>>> f.__code__.co_varnames
('x',)
>>> f.__code__.co_consts
(None, 3)
>>> import dis
>>> instructions = dis.get_instructions(f)
>>> instructions
<generator object _get_instructions_bytes at 0x10be77048>
>>> instruction = next(instructions)
>>> instruction
Instruction(opname='LOAD_FAST', opcode=124, arg=0, argval='x', argrepr='x', offset=0, starts_line=2, is_jump_target=False)
```

So the first opcode, 124 or `LOAD_FAST` puts the value for first local name on the stack; this is the `0 0` argument, little-endian interpreted as integer `0`, an index into the code locals array. `dis` has filled out the `argval` attribute, showing us that the first local name is `x`. In the above session I show how you can introspect the code object to see the list of names.

```
>>> instruction = next(instructions)
>>> instruction
Instruction(opname='LOAD_CONST', opcode=100, arg=1, argval=3, argrepr='3', offset=3, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
```

The next instruction pushes a constant onto the stack; the argument is now `1 0`, or little-endian for integer `1`; the second constant associated with the code object. The `f.__code__.co_consts` tuple shows that it is `3`, but the `Instruction` object gives it too, as the `argval` attribute.

```
>>> next(instructions)
Instruction(opname='LOAD_FAST', opcode=124, arg=0, argval='x', argrepr='x', offset=6, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
```

Next we have another `LOAD_FAST`, pushing another reference to local name `x` onto the stack.

```
>>> next(instructions)
Instruction(opname='BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE', opcode=27, arg=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=9, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
```

This is a bytecode *without argument*, the opcode 27 is below `dis.HAVE_ARGUMENT`. No argument is needed, because this opcode takes the top two values on the stack, divides them, pushing the floating point result back on the stack. So the last `x` and the `3` constant are taken, divided and the result is push back on.

```
>>> next(instructions)
Instruction(opname='BINARY_ADD', opcode=23, arg=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=10, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
```

Another argument-less bytecode; this one adds up the top two stack values, replacing those with the outcome. The outcome of the `BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE` is taken, and the value of `x` that was pushed on first, and the result is put back on the stack.

```
>>> next(instructions)
Instruction(opname='RETURN_VALUE', opcode=83, arg=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=11, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
```

Last instruction, and another that doesn't take arguments. `RETURN_VALUE` ends the current frame, returning the top value from the stack as the result to the caller.

Comment: So that's one guy saying big-endian, and another saying little-endian.

Comment: Big-endian? The bytecode in the OP looks like the 1 is represented in little-endian. Do you have a reference or source link I could look at?

Comment: @user2357112: ++++ OUT OF CAFFEINE ERROR +++ REDO FROM START ++++ I was wrong, corrected.

Comment: Oh wow, that's incredibly useful! Thanks for teaching me about it!

Answer (score 6):

Before CPython 3.6, CPython bytecode arguments take 2 bytes. The extra zeros are the high bytes of the arguments.

Comment: I see, do you think you could elaborate on the difference between "low" bytes and high bytes, or link me to something that would explain it?

Comment: Would that make Python big-endian or little-endian? I can never get those two straight.

Comment: @user3002473: The high byte of a 2-byte integer is to the integer as 9 is to 93 in a 2-decimal-digit representation.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: Little-endian.

Comment: @user2357112 Okay, I think I understand. What problems would I run into if I just used the low byte to index `f.__code__.co_varnames` and `f.__code__.co_consts`?

Comment: @user3002473: If the argument is greater than 255, you'll only get the last 8 bits of it. That'll be a problem if the code uses more than 255 variables or 255 constants, such as if there's a really long list literal. If the arguments get *really* big, you'll need to handle [extended arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-EXTENDED_ARG), where a separate opcode provides two additional bytes of argument.

Comment: @user2357112 Okay, so assuming i & j are the low and high bytes respectively I should actually be indexing with `i + (j << 8)` and not just `i`? And (with i, j, k & l being the 4-bytes) if there are 4-bytes I'd assume the index would have to be `i + (j << 8) + (k << 16) + (l << 32)`?

Comment: @user3002473: `(l << 24)`, not `32`, but other than that, yup.