# What are all that zeros in python bytecode and how to compute them

Tags: python, bytecode, python-3.12

When I do `list(some_function.__code__.co_code)` I can see the actual bytecode of that function (in list[int] format). And I see that there are a lot of zeros - actually more than in earlier versions of python. Yeah, I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083861/what-do-the-zeros-in-python-function-bytecode-mean) question, but if I create that function in python 3.12, there are more zeros in the bytecode. My question is: "what do all that zeros mean and **if** I want to write bytecode, how can I compute how many zeros are needed?"

See what happens:

```py
def f(x):
    return x + x/3

bytecode = list(f.__code__.co_code)
print(bytecode)
```

prints:

> [151, 0, 124, 0, 100, 1, 124, 0, 122, 11, 0, 0, 122, 0, 0, 0, 83, 0]

```py
def f(x):
    return x + x/3

dis.dis(f, show_caches=True)
```

gives:

```
  1           0 RESUME                   0
  2           2 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              8 BINARY_OP               11 (/)
             10 CACHE                    0 (counter: 0)
             12 BINARY_OP                0 (+)
             14 CACHE                    0 (counter: 0)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is different of the code in the already mentioned code at a couple of points:

- First we have `RESUME` in front, this is for debug purposes, as mentioned in [the official dis reference](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/dis.html#opcode-RESUME)
- Also it is slightly different when binary operations are done, instead of using one bytecode that stands for one operation, there is only one opcode, for all operations, with an argument of which operation to do.
- The main difference is, however, that there are at some points less zeros, and at other points more...

What's going on here? And why use all opcodes one argument (also the one which opcode is less than `dis.HAVE_ARGUMENT`)

Where this is not *super* strange it gets somewhat stranger when dealing with the following function:

```py
def f():
    print("hello world!")
```

bytecode: `[151, 0, 116, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 1, 171, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 121, 0]`

Could someone also explain all these zeros?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I see that all that zeros are CACHE opcodes, but how to compute how many CACHEs are needed?

**EDIT**

There is a suggestion that the `0`s in the bytecode are arguments not CACHE, but that assertion appears incorrect.

Looking at an annotated output of:

```py
def f():
    print("hello world!")

print(list(f.__code__.co_code))

for instr in dis.Bytecode(f):
  print(instr.opname, instr.opcode, instr.arg)
```

One can see:

```
[151, 0, 116, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 1, 171, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 121, 0]
   |  |    |  |                            |  |    |  |                    |  |    |  |
   |  |    |  |                            |  |    |  |                    |  |    |  |
   |  |    |  |                            |  |    |  |                    |  |    |  |
   |  |    |  |                            |  |    |  |                    |  |    |  |
   |--|    |--|---------|                  |  |    |  |                    |  |    |  |
   |--|---------------| |                  |  |    |  |                    |  |    |  |
                      | |                  |  |    |  |                    |  |    |  |
RESUME 151 0        --| |                  |  |    |  |                    |  |    |  |
LOAD_GLOBAL 116 1   ----|                  |  |    |  |                    |  |    |  |
LOAD_CONST 100 1    -----------------------|--|    |  |                    |  |    |  |
CALL 171 1          -------------------------------|--|                    |  |    |  |
POP_TOP 1 None      -------------------------------------------------------|--|    |  |
RETURN_CONST 121 0  ---------------------------------------------------------------|--|
```

Many of these `0` values not pointed to by the loop are indicated to be "CACHE" by `dis.dis(f, show_caches=True)`

Comment: Please dont ask me for a use case, because I dont know a use case, I only want to **know** how it works

Comment: No, the zeros are not all CACHE opcodes. The byte code is not *just* a list of opcodes, but a sequence of opcodes *and* the argument(s) for each opcode. You can't guess whether a particular byte in the sequence is an opcode or not without knowing what all the previous bytes represent.

Comment: Perhaps this might help a bit : https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-CACHE

Comment: There is no useful reason to write bytecode. What would you do with it? There is a book `CPython Internals: Your Guide to the Python 3 Interpreter Anthony Shaw` if you want to delve into this.

Comment: @JonSG `CACHE` isn't relative here; none of the 0s in this function refer to the `CACHE` opcode, but are arguments to other opcodes.

Comment: @chepner I think the op is looking to understand all the CACHE results coming from `dis.dis(f, show_caches=True)`

Comment: these zeros are clearly meaning cache, run dis with `show_caches=True` shows that

Comment: @jonSG yes, there im looking for

Comment: "Many opcodes expect to be followed by an exact number of caches, and will instruct the interpreter to skip over them at runtime." Which operations require caches does not appear to be documented. (Unless you count CPython source code as documentation.)

Comment: how could i than find out how many caches are needed?

Comment: Read the Python source code. Byte code is only an implementation detail of CPython, not an inherent part of Python programming; they are irrelevant to, for example, PyPy.

Comment: Note the "practical" part of the "practical, answerable questions" criteria (likewise, "based on actual problems you face") at https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are asking the question feels strange to me, because I think what you want to know is how to write bytecode instructions and then convert it to bytecode bytes.

For writing bytecode and having it get converted to a bytecode file, see [xasm](https://github.com/rocky/python-xasm). This is on PyPI but I haven't put out a new release this in quite a while. So build from source on github.

For understanding how bytecode works interactively, see [x-python](https://github.com/rocky/x-python). Same story with respect to being on PyPI and a new release. And for x-python, there is even a debugger that will let you single step instructions. That is called [trepan-xpy](https://github.com/rocky/trepan-xpy). This might be the hardest to install because has a lot of dependencies, such as the [trepan debugger](https://github.com/rocky/trepan-xpy).

I will be [talking](https://www.blackhat.com/asia-24/briefings/schedule/index.html#how-to-get-the-most-out-of-the-python-decompilers-uncompyle-and-decompyle---how-to-write-and-read-a-bytecode-decompiler-37789) at [BlackHat Asia](https://www.blackhat.com/asia-24/) mid April 2024, so there may be new releases sometime a little before that.

Before I attempt to answer your question as stated let me give an analogous situation. Suppose I am trying to learn numbers. And I see there are all these different flavors of base system (which is analogous to Python bytecode versions).  Someone asks why are there more zeros the binary version of the numbers than in the base 10 version of then numbers? Well that's because there are fewer digits to pick so each digit appears more often.

In bytecode, you'll see a lot of zeros because zero is the smallest integer and a number of operands of instructions are indexes into table of some sort such as a tuple of constants, tuple of variable names. If the tuple is not empty, then it will have a 0 item. And since the tuple are by some need for it the 0th item will probably have one instruction with an operand of 0.

As was mentioned before 0, is also used in bytecode as a placeholder when there is no value. So instructions that don't have an operand typically put 0 in there. I don't know if this is strictly required. Someone might check if some other value will work, and the Python interpreter will ignore that as good as it ignores the operand with value 0.

Comment: nice answer, but still my question is: How to compute how many zeros are needed?

Comment: The number of 0's needed depends on what you are trying to express. Suppose I asked how many "e"'s are needed to when I write a book? (There is a book written in English that uses no "e"''s at all.